# How to swap and remove columns using awk without getting newlines and whitespace?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk

For example I have following .csv delimited by ';'.
I need to swap 2 columns and/or delete some.

col1row1;col2row1;col3row1
col1row2;col2row2;col3row2
col1row3;col2row3;col3row3
...

Column's number is not fixed, columns I need to swap can be different.
I've used **awk 'BEGIN {FS=";";OFS=";"} {print $3, $1}'**, but it adding newlines if one of swapping column was the last one like

col3row1
;col1row1
col3row2
;col1row2
col3row3
;col1row3
...

or whitespaces for smth like **{print $2, $1, $3}**

col2row1;  col1row1  ;col3row1
col2row2;  col1row2  ;col3row2
col2row3;  col1row3  ;col3row3
...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input file contains control-Ms. Run `dos2unix` or similar to remove them.

Comment: Yep, that was the problem. Used **sed 's/\r//'** before using awk.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F ";" '{printf("%s;%s;%s\n", $2, $1, $3)}'
```

EDIT: Or with sed:

```
sed -r 's/^([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*)/\3;\2;\1/'
```

Comment: Still getting newline with **{printf("%s;%s\n", $3, $1)}**